# how do i use Virtual Audio Cable to assign programs to specific audio outputs in win 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have to same problem in [Assigning programs to specific audio outputs in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/73921/assigning-programs-to-specific-audio-outputs-in-windows-7) . 
one of the answer suggested to use virtual audio cable. I have downloaded the trial version but i have totally no ideas how to assign programs to specific audio outputs.

Comment: Have you read the manual? Also, try giving a comment on his answer, he will probably know how to do it and might not see this question.

Comment: @TomWij: You need 50 rep to comment.

Comment: Ah, yeah... Long time ago for me, that's explains why new people create questions or answers instead of commenting. It's actually not the right way, if it annoys me at one or another point I might make a Meta Question for it, but well. If he has read the manual and it doesn't work we can try and explain him, it's a legal question after all. :-)