# Assigning audio device output on an application level in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning programs to specific audio outputs in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/73921/assigning-programs-to-specific-audio-outputs-in-windows-7)

There's some programs where I can't set which audio device I would like to use (e.g., iTunes), forcing me to use Window's default and I'm wondering if theres some way I can set each application running in Windows 7 to use a specific audio output.

My googlefu has failed me but I'm hoping theres something out there as I couldn't think of any good search terms.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://forums.techguy.org/all-other-software/940087-change-audio-output-device-any.html) has a link to several programs, including Indie Volume and Virtual Audio Cable, that may do what you're looking for.